# How compare float and ArrayList object in c#

Tags: c#

I want to compare the array element with number.

```
ArrayList arr_obj = new ArrayList();
double a=1;

arr_obj.Add(1);
arr_obj.Add(2);

for(i = 0; i < arr_obj.Count; i++)
{
    if (arr_obj[i] == a) 
    {
        Debug.Log("ext");
    }
}
```

This code does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Not worked? Not very helpful.

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` anymore. It belongs old times when C# doesn't support _generics_. Use `List<T>` instead..

Comment: Use `List<int>` for your case and if you like to use it as *Heterogeneous Collection* use `List<object>`

Answer (score 2):

Yo are comparing an object to a double which won't compile. You will either have to store doubles in the ArrayList (as below) or first cast the values to int and then to double Ie `(double)(int)arr_obj[i]` because you can only unbox to the exact same type as you boxed (in your case that's `int`)

If you wish to stick to an ArrayList, not recommended, change to

```
 ArrayList arr_obj = new ArrayList();
 double a=1.0;

 arr_obj.Add(1.0);
 arr_obj.Add(2.0);

 for(i=0;i<arr_obj.Count;i++){
            if ((double)arr_obj[i]==a) {
                   Debug.Log("ext");
            }
        }
```

or you could use a `List<double>`

```
 var list = new List<double>{1.0,2.0};
 var a=1.0;

 for(i=0;i<list.Count;i++){
        if (list[i]==a) {
               Debug.Log("ext");
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the ArrayList to double:

```
(double)arr_obj[i]
```

ArrayList can contain any type beacause it is a list of objects. So, if you are going to cast it like this, you need to be sure that each array list is of type double by only putting doubles in the array list, or check it before casting like:

```
if (arr_obj[i] is double)
{
    if ((double)arr_obj[i] == a)
    {   
        Console.WriteLine(arr_obj[i].ToString() + " is double");
    }
}
```

Comment: The values in the arraylist are not doubles, they are ints, so the cast will simply throw an exception.

Comment: You will need to unbox as an `int`  and then cast to `double`. Ie `(double)(int)arr_obj[i] == a`

Comment: I added a check to see if it is a double.

Comment: But in the code posted by the OP, they're _not_ doubles. They're ints. That if block will be skipped every time.

Comment: Yes I know, good point. But the point is that if there is a double it will hit the if. In his example he should add variable a to the list, it is double.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it with Convert.ToDouble(arr_obj[i])